# How can I add extra disk space to my elasticsearch nodes

Tags: linux, docker, elasticsearch

The set up is 3 nodes, two warm nodes with 5TBs of storage and a hot node with 2TB. I want to add 2TBs of storage to each of the two nodes.

Each node is run as a docker image on a Linux server which will be shutdown while adding the disks. I do not know how to make elasticsearch utilize the extra space after adding the disks.

No docker-compose files are used.

The elastic image is started without specifying volumes, but only specifies the elasticsearch yaml file. The elasticsearch file does not mention anything about the path properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple data path, editing the yaml configuration file:

```
path:
  data:
    - /mnt/disk_1
    - /mnt/disk_2
    - /mnt/disk_3
```

In recent ElasticSearch versions, this option is deprecated.
See [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/important-settings.html#_multiple_data_paths) to migrate to an alternative configuration.